# Looking for more flexible wire for jumpers used inside a wall switch box

Tags: wiring

I've been installing "Smart" switches in my home.  My home was built in 1970 and has all BX type wiring with metal switch boxes.
The smart switches are larger than the original simple switches so I need to pay more attention to the positioning of the wires in the box.

Question:
Is there a "to code" option of a more flexible wire I could use to connect multiple neutrals (or line) to these smart switches?
I (think) know it needs to be #14 and 600V.  THHN is stranded but it is barely more flexible than solid.  I only need a few 4 or 5" lengths to make these connections much easier to position in the box.

Thanks

Comment: Do your "smart switches" have pigtails or side-screw terminations?

Comment: They have side screws, the Pig tailed ones are usually pretty flexible.

Comment: Are they screw-only, or do they also accept clamp-type backwiring?

Comment: Use stranded #14 and use Wago 221s instead of twist nuts to gain a little flexibility, literally, in positioning the wires behind the switch.   If you have older single-device metal boxes that are smaller than a modern one gang box you may need to replace them.  Depending on the exact box and the device, I have had combinations that absolutely won't fit.

Comment: THHN comes in stranded and solid. I've found the stranded to be quite flexible when doing the wiring in my new addition. However, I've also used 4" square boxes with single- and double-gang mud rings (as appropriate) because I've been in the "there's just not enough space in this box!" situation before...

Answer (score 1):

XHHW is the 'more flexible' alternative to THHN, though it can be more difficult to find outside of an electrical supply store (looks like Lowe's has some).

In this situation, I would trim the building wire back (leaving as much as is reasonable), stick a Wago 221 on it, and use XHHW in the box.

Comment: Depending on the switch termination and the connectors used, there might be a way to use a building-wiring-rated fine-strand wire in the OP's situation, but I'd need more details to judge that